Animating annular sectors, vertices along a circular path, using skeletons
I need to create an animation of planar data to look like the following (without the slider):

This is two annular sectors that are growing in length (increasing angle), one annular sector that is shrinking (decreasing angle), and two sectors that are growing (increasing in angle). The annular sectors are "stroked" with fully-opaque black along their edges.
The green, blue, and pink regions are all semi-transparent, so they cannot overlap. There is a region visible below the graphic, so I cannot rotate covered-up semi-circles into place.
This needs to be exported via glTF to a custom game engine, so I must use skeletal animation. (I cannot use the AnimAll extension to animate vertices per frame...which would need a lot of custom baking, or precise interpolation handle editing to move along a circular path.)
Let's ignore the black outlines, because those are easy, and focus on just the sectors and annular sectors.
I've created geometry and skinned them to rotating bones. (I've evenly spaced the geometry and bones for the common case.) The result looks good enough in the middle of the animation (or when covered by bones):

...but as you can see, at the extremes the outline moves out of circle, and the vertices start to pile up badly, causing faces to overlap and ruining a uniform semi-transparency:

Other than throwing more bones at the problem (one bone per radial line?), is there a way to animate this in a circular fashion?

Edit: to avoid an XY problem, I suppose I should say that it does not HAVE to be skeletal animation. It occurred to me while writing this up that the runtime engine does support KHR_animation_pointer glTF extension, so perhaps I could accomplish the result with static geometry and animating a texture's UV offset to somehow slide in a radial fashion?

I would recommend making the outer part border, or at least the purple bits a separate mesh from the circular part. Since only one part of it needs to actually move you can avoid the border getting squished.
